# Add a remote schema on Hasura from localhost rails server fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, hasura

I am testing Hasura with docker on my localhost, and I would like to add a remote schema, from a graphql endpoint on my local environment (rails app, `http://localhost:3000/graphql`)

When I try to add the remote schema URL on Hasura (via `http://host.docker.internal:3000/graphql`), it fails with the following message:

```
Adding remote schema failed
Error in $: Failed reading: not a valid json value at '<!DOCTYPEhtml>'
```

And, I have no log on my rails server.

I tried to use ngrok to have an `https` endpoint, (`https://6e12fa99336b.ngrok.io` forwarding to `localhost:3000`) but I had the same message. My ngrok console did show a post to `/graphql`, with `403 Forbidden`, and still no log on the rails server

However it works with a public external API (`https://countries.trevorblades.com/graphql` for instance)

Is there something that I am doing wrong, some headers missing ?

Comment: Hi friend, it seems the issue is your rails app is returning HTML instead of JSON at that endpoint

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your response. Indeed the rails app returns html and 403 forbidden result. but I can’t figure out why. The endpoint I configured is the graphQL api endpoint of my rails app which returns json… 
I don’t see no logs warning me that the forgery protection reset the session. And no log at all in the rails development console. This is why I was wondering if I forgot a header or anything else

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got it ! The issue was with rails, not having `host.docker.internal` as a registered host, thus rendering an HTML error page.
After adding `host.docker.internal` to `config.host` everything worked.